# Add filter function in media modal box

Tags: backbone, media-modal

I'm trying to extend the media modal, but I cant' find any documentation / tutorials about it. I'm not a master of backbone too ;-)

I want to add a select box for each taxonomy that is attached to the attachment post type. At the moment only one select box is shown.

So this is what I came up with. It works great except that it replaces the default toolbar.

---

### Code

```
/**
 * Extended Filters dropdown with taxonomy term selection values
 */
jQuery.each(mediaTaxonomies,function(key,label){

    media.view.AttachmentFilters[key] = media.view.AttachmentFilters.extend({
        className: key,

        createFilters: function() {
            var filters = {};

            _.each( mediaTerms[key] || {}, function( term ) {

                var query = {};

                query[key] = {
                    taxonomy: key,
                    term_id: parseInt( term.id, 10 ),
                    term_slug: term.slug
                };

                filters[ term.slug ] = {
                    text: term.label,
                    props: query
                };
            });

            this.filters = filters;
        }

    });

    /**
     * Replace the media-toolbar with our own
     */
    media.view.AttachmentsBrowser = media.view.AttachmentsBrowser.extend({
        createToolbar: function() {

            media.model.Query.defaultArgs.filterSource = 'filter-media-taxonomies';

            this.toolbar = new media.view.Toolbar({
                controller: this.controller
            });

            this.views.add( this.toolbar );

            this.toolbar.set( 'terms', new media.view.AttachmentFilters[key]({
                controller: this.controller,
                model:      this.collection.props,
                priority:   -80
            }).render() );
        }
    });

});
```

---

### Original

[image]

---

### My result

[image]

---

### What I want

[image]

---

### Full code

https://github.com/Horttcore/Media-Taxonomies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wonderful world of Backbone.js and WP (of which I know barely anything).

I think the problem is you are just calling the same default `media.view`, instead I believe you need to initialize a new one.

For example:

```
/**
 * Replace the media-toolbar with our own
 */
    var myDrop = media.view.AttachmentsBrowser;

    media.view.AttachmentsBrowser = media.view.AttachmentsBrowser.extend({
    createToolbar: function() {

        media.model.Query.defaultArgs.filterSource = 'filter-media-taxonomies';

        myDrop.prototype.createToolbar.apply(this,arguments);

        this.toolbar.set( key, new media.view.AttachmentFilters[key]({
            controller: this.controller,
            model:      this.collection.props,
            priority:   -80
        }).render() );
    }
});
```

Would give you *something* like below (I did not do any thorough error checking but it does work).

---

[image]

---

You should also consider doing this with `media.view.AttachmentFilters` and anything custom with regards to `window.wp.media;`.

Comment: Awesome thank you!
I should read about backbone.js soon, as it seems it gets more integrated in every new WP version.

Comment: Thank you for making this a plugin so it was easy to answer:) In fact you have inspired my to make a github plugin for WPSE questions.