# Media Library modal customization

Tags: media, media-library, media-modal

I have a fashion website and I use a large amount of images on my website, As I add new products I should add product images and for that I use media library modal [image]
but the problem is working with this feature is very hard because I should search my product images from thousand of images and for that I should scroll down and wait and then scroll down and wait and it takes hours to do that , is it a way to customize this modal for example loading more images in each scroll call or make it with pagination so I can skip some pages .

please help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, in the Media Upload Modal Box you can only filter by Date (Month uploaded) and/or Search. To fully take advantage of the search function you should have proper filenames, alt text and description of every image when you upload them.

For pagination you can go to your Media Gallery and turn on List Mode:
[image: WP Media Library List Mode]

Or directly by visiting: https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list

If you want to customize the modal box and extend its functionality to filter by taxonomies like this:
[image]

please have a look [at this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114205/160985). You can find the full code for Media Taxonomies at GitHub [here](https://github.com/Horttcore/Media-Taxonomies).